# Slide div left with infinite options

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created an mini slide with 4 images: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uy6je/).

But the divs are breaking on the containers limit and therefore are being shown only 2 divs instead of 4. Also i need to make this mini slider infinite, someone could show me how can I do?

Look at my code:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="right_curriculum_container">
<div class="left_arroq"><img src="img/1_c_left_arrow.png" id="left_arrow" width="26" height="26" alt="Previous" title="Previous"></div>
<div id="image_container">

<div class="center_image"></div>
<div class="center_image"></div>

<div class="center_image"></div>
<div class="center_image"></div>

</div>
<div class="left_arroq"><img src="img/1_c_right_arrow.png" id="right_arrow" width="26" height="26" alt="Next" title="Next"></div>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.left_arroq {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 110px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;  
}
#right_arrow {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#left_arrow {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#image_container {
    height: 250px;
    width: 350px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    float: left;
    overflow:hidden;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.center_image {
    height: 235px;
    width: 163px;
    background-color: #606060;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 8px;
    border: 2px solid #7ACBBF;
    margin-top: 6px;
    position: relative;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#left_arrow').click(function() {
$('.center_image').animate({
left : "-350px" //moves left
});
   });

    $('#right_arrow').click(function() {
$('.center_image').animate({
left : "0px" //moves right
});
     });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the 2 images versus 4, your width of the `#image_container` is set to 350px ... where your individual images widths are set to 163px respectively.  So you need a minimum of 163 * 4.  Setting it to 700px does the trick.

```
#image_container 
{
    height: 250px;
    width: 700px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    float: left;
    overflow:hidden;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

### [See workfing jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/63AZs/)

Comment: Thanks Maverick, but this code show all divs and i need to show only 2 divs per click, and if i set container width to 700px this break my layout. Is there any solution to show only 2 divs at a time and not break my layout that needs to be 350px? Thanks!

Comment: I'm solved a break layout problem adding a New Container (div) wrapping all: JSFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Uy6je/1/) . But now i'm trying to make this slider infinite. Any help?